Why does this go into an infinite loop?
I am trying to maintain a string that will contain all the authors' names.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,authblk}
\def\authorsnames{}
\newcommand*{\addauthor}[2]{\author[#2]{#1} \IfNoValueTF{\authorsnames}{\def\authorsnames{#1}}{\def\authorsnames{\authorsnames, #1}}}
\addauthor{My name}{My University}
\addauthor{My friend}{Friend's University}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorsnames}

However, I get the following error message:

TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].

I'm assuming it is because something loops here with no stop. My assumption is that "\def\authorsnames" holds a pointer to its own value, instead of simply treating that value as a string and concatenating it? Seems pretty weird.
My goal is to have a string that will hold the following value: My name, My friend. At first, the string will be empty. Then, I will invoke \addauthor{My name}{My University} to make it become My name because so far (prior) the value for authorsnames is empty. Then, I will invoke \addauthor{My friend}{Friend's University} to make authorsnames become My name, My friend because it will add the string My friend to the parameter \authorsnames, that already holds a value and is not empty.

Probably \def\authorsnames{\authorsnames, #1}, that is not really how LaTeX works. What is your end goal here?

\expandafter\def\expandafter\authorsnames\expandafter{\authorsnames, #1}. Or with expl3 syntax \tl_put_right:Nn\authornames{,#1}

@daleif To have a list of all the authors' names.

def\authorsnames{\authorsnames, #1} is like \def\oops{\oops x} so it is explicitly coding a loop. \oops expands to \oops x which expands to \oops xx which expands to  \oops xxx and so on until you fill the stack.

As noted above, LaTeX does not allow the kind of self-reference definitions, that would be allowed in many other programming languages. For example, in shell scripts I could write x=Hello"; x="$x World."; echo "$x" and that would respond Hello World. But in LaTeX you must do some kind of intermediate processing, as described above.

@rallg you can do something equivalent to your bash example but the tex syntax for that uses \edef not \def

@DavidCarlisle That is worth knowing, about \edef. I had been using a two-step method with an intermediate variable.

One reason for memory problems is the line
\newcommand*{\addauthor}[2]{\author[#2]{#1} \IfNoValueTF{\authorsnames}{\def\authorsnames{#1}}{\def\authorsnames{\authorsnames, #1}}}

After initializing \authorsnames empty via \def\authorsnames{}, carrying out \addauthor the first time yields carrying out the definition
\def\authorsnames{\authorsnames, ⟨tokens coming from \addauthor's first argument⟩}.
This is because emptiness is not the same as the xparse-no-value-marker, thus after initializing \authorsnames empty \addauthor's \IfNoValueFT-test in any case yields the F-branch.
Subsequent calls to \addauthor also yield carrying out that definition as with subsequent calls to \addauthor the macro \authorsnames in any case also is not/yields not exactly the xparse-no-value-marker.
After carrying out the definition
\def\authorsnames{\authorsnames, ⟨tokens coming from \addauthor's first argument⟩},
\authorsnames is a recursive loop which is carried out in the stage of expansion. One iteration of the loop is formed by expanding and thus removing a token \authorsnames and as replacement text producing another token \authorsnames which is trailed by the token ,12 and the token ␣10 and the tokens coming from the first argument of the last instance of \addauthor. So more and more instances of the token sequence formed by the token ,12 and the token ␣10 and the tokens coming from the first argument of the last instance of \addauthor are accumulated in the "token queue" behind one token \authorsnames. That "token queue" is called "input stack". The loop is recursive, but​—⁠despite there not being any explicit conditional expression for terminating the loop⁠—​it is not really infinite because in any case there is a moment when the amount of memory reserved as the TeX program's input stack is too small to hold the token \authorsnames and all the tokens of the "token queue" behind \authorsnames. This is the moment when TeX bails out with an error message like
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
This happens with the recursive "expansion cascade" initiated by expanding \authorsnames in the course of processing/carrying out \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorsnames}.
One might probably do s.th. like this:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,authblk}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Initialize \authorsnames to the xparse-no-value-marker as otherwise
% the \IfNoValueTF-test with \addauthor won't work out:
% ( Instead, you could initialize \authorsnames empty and use the
%   \IfBlankTF-test, but that probably is not complicated enough. )
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begingroup
\NewDocumentCommand\authorsnames{o}{%
  \endgroup
  \def\authorsnames{#1}%
}\authorsnames\relax
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%\show\authorsnames
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% For appending to \authorsnames use \edef/\xdef...{\unexpanded{...}}.
% This way hash-tokens ( # of category 6=parameter ) delivered via the
% first argument of \addauthor to the <balanced text> of the <definition>
% of \authorsnames get doubled in the <balanced text> of the <definition>
% of authorsnames.
% This doubling of hash-tokens is needed for 
% - avoiding single hash-tokens delivered via the first argument of
%   \addauthor to the <balanced text> of the <definition> of
%   \authorsnames being taken for parameters of the <definition> of
%   \authorsnames that denote arguments of the macro \authorsnames
%   while the <parameter text> of that <definition> is empty.
% - compensating the fact that pairs of hash-tokens ( ## ) occurring
%   in the <balanced text> of the <definition> of \authorsnames
%   collapse into a single hash-token ( # ) when expanding \authorsnames.
% Actually this is sort of obsolete as \hypersetup of the package
% hyperref does not take into account such things, thus things with
% hashes explode. But the possible "exploding" of \hypersetup is not
% a reason for oneself deviating from habits that usually form good
% practice.
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*{\addauthor}[2]{%
  \author[{#2}]{#1}% <- The additional {...} surrounding #2 is in case #2 itself contains [...]
  \xdef\authorsnames{%
    \expandafter\IfNoValueF
    \expandafter{\authorsnames}%
                {\unexpanded\expandafter{\authorsnames, }}%
    \unexpanded{#1}%
  }%
}
\addauthor{My name}{My University}
%\show\authorsnames
\addauthor{My friend}{Friend's University}
%\show\authorsnames
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorsnames}

\stop

